# LINQ Select only throws IOException when the Enumerable is looked at

Tags: c#, linq, ioexception

I'm currently using LINQ to load a list of files into XDocuments, like so:

```
 var fileNames = new List<string>(){ "C:\file.xml" };

 var xDocs = fileNames.Select(XDocument.Load);

 var xDocs2 = xDocs.ToList(); // Crashes here
```

If I deliberately 'lock' one of the files with a different process, the IOException is only thrown when I actually start to look at the XDocuments I've been generating, ie when ToList() is called.

Can anyone explain why this is, and how best to handle this error? I'd like to have access to the working XDocuments still, if possible.

Comment: what is the exception message.

Comment: Keyword here is `deferred execution`

Comment: How to best handle this error is to use `foreach` loops instead of Linq - especially for tasks that require error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why this is

As many pointed out, this is because of the so called **deferred execution** of many LINQ methods. For instanse, the `Enumerable.Select` method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) states

> This method is implemented by using **deferred execution**. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its **GetEnumerator** method directly or by using **foreach** in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

while the `Enumerable.ToList` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) contains

> The ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method **forces immediate query evaluation** and returns a List that contains the query results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy of the query results.

So the `XDocument.Load` is really executed for each file name during the `ToList` call. I guess that covers the **why** part.

> and how best to handle this error? I'd like to have access to the working XDocuments still, if possible.

I don't know what does "best" mean in this context, but if you want to ignore the errors and include the "working XDocuments", then you can use something like this

```
var xDocs = fileNames.Select(fileName =>
{
    try { return XDocument.Load(fileName); }
    catch { return null; }
});
```

and then either append `.Where(doc => doc != null)`, or account for `null` documents when processing the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is why the linq .Select is an IEnumerable and the elements are first called if you make your IEnumerable to an List. Then you go through all of your elements.